# Function for check empty elements of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to create function for checking empty elements of HTML.

Javascript code:

```
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
  function getParamNames(params, formName, errorMSG) {
    if(result!="" && formName!=""){
      var fnStr = params.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
      var result = fnStr.slice(fnStr.indexOf('(')+1, fnStr.indexOf(')')).match(/([^\s,]+)/g).toString();
      alert(document.frm.result.value);
      return false;
    }
    else{
      alert("Параметры функции не были заданы в JavaScript. Пожалуйста обратитесь к программистам.");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

HTML code:

```
<form name='frm' method='post' action='' onSubmit="getParamNames(function(ggg){}, 'frm', 'Хамаи катакчахо бояд пур карда шавад');">
   <input type="text" name="ggg" />
   <input type="submit" value="ssdfsdfdf" />
</form>
```

and I get this error: 
**TypeError: document.frm.result is undefined**

```
alert(document.frm.result.value);
```

Comment: An element is empty if it has no child nodes. You can do this with the DOM, no need for regex.

Comment: @elclanrs how can I do it with DOM?

Comment: The message is terrible: "Параметры функции не были заданы в JavaScript. Пожалуйста обратитесь к программистам!" It's even worst than Excel notifications. After you fixing the code, try to think one more time how it looks like for customers, please!

Comment: @m59 I found answer for my question, thanks.

Comment: @Mr.AbduJan Will you please accept my answer then!!! I'm so confused!

Answer (score 3):

I would just use dom reference to do this.

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/iCobEcU/1/edit)

```
//get a reference to all elements
var allElems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

var emptyElems = []; //store empty elements here
for (var i=0; i<allElems.length; ++i) { //check each element for text or children
  if (!allElems[i].textContent && !allElems[i].hasChildNodes()) {
    emptyElems.push(allElems[i]); //add empty elements to array
  }
}

console.log(emptyElems);
```